# Vertical Snap in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to snap windows vertically in Windows 8? If not, is there an app that allows such command to be implemented (or programmed)?

When coding on a secondary monitor that's vertical, oftentimes I don't need the entire screen. Since the screen is vertical, it make more sense to snap the windows vertically. The default "snap" features carried over from Windows Aero seem to only allow for horizontal snaps (Win+Left/Right).

*Note: I know there's the "show windows stacked" option from the toolbar but that's more of a clumsy hack than a solution.*

Comment: windows 8 metro app only have snap view in landscape. snapping can be down to left or right of the screen. but in portrait view - there is no snapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this program, it remembers a window's last size and position:
WindowManager by DeskSoft . . . http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm

Seemingly related:
In Excel 2010, open two spreadsheets
View tab / View Side by Side / Synchronous Scrolling
View tab / Arrange All / Tiled - Horizontal - Vertical - Cascade

Answer (score -1):

Found this through another website and by playing around (Windows 8.1)...

```
<win><left cursor> - snaps app/window left
<win><right cursor> - snaps app/window right
<win><down cursor> - closes app (minimises window if in Desktop mode)
<win><up cursor> - maximises app/window
```

Also, if you have an app snapped, you can use the {win}{cursor key} to move it from side to side etc.
If you have two snapped, adding a third can be moved with the cursor keys and then enter to (re)place a snapped app.